# Store user input using forms or models in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a **Django** ML web app where the user inputs some values and the ML models calculates a value and return it. What I want to do is **save those values entered by the user and later use those values to retrain the ML model**. Basically the user input should be saved in the database and later I should be able to fetch it for retraining. I have a couple questions regarding this:

1.) Should I use forms for saving user input or should I use models?

2.) What is the difference between using forms or models for saving user input?

Any links/material/tutorial would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The forms do in fact work with the models. The models act as an ORM between django and the database. You will need to [create the models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/), then depending on your project, either make this data available via an API or if you only need it within the project, simply call your models and that will query your database.

I would recommend doing some individual research into django models and how to use them correctly. The idea is that you will save your data in the database through your models, then when you need it you can query it back.

[Useful page for learning django models](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models)